# Repeatedly interpolating from scattered to regular grid with varying sample values

Tags: performance, matlab, interpolation

I want to do scattered interpolation in Matlab, but `scatteredInterpolant` does not do quite what I want.

`scatteredInterpolant` allows me to provide a set of input sampling positions and the corresponding sample values. Then I can query the interpolated values by supplying a set of positions:

```
F = scatteredInterpolant(xpos, ypos, samplevals)
interpvals = F(xgrid, ygrid)
```

This is sort of the opposite of what I want. I already have a fixed set of sample positions, `xpos/ypos`, and output grid, `xgrid/ygrid`, and then I want to vary the sample values. The use case is that I have many quantities sampled at the same sampling positions, that should all be interpolated to the same output grid.

I have an idea how to do this for nearest neighbor and linear interpolation, but not for more general cases, in particular for natural neighbor interpolation.

This is what I want, in mock code:

```
G = myScatteredInterpolant(xpos, ypos, xgrid, ygrid, interp_method)
interpvals = G(samplevals)
```

In terms of what this means, I suppose `G` holds a (presumably sparse) matrix of weights, `W`, and then `G(samplevals)` basically does `W * samplevals`, where the weights in the matrix `W` depends on the input and output grid, as well as the interpolation method (nearest neighbor, linear, natural neighbor). Calculating the matrix `W` is probably much more expensive than evaluating the product `W * samplevals`, which is why I want this to be reused.

Is there any code in Matlab, or in a similar language that I could adapt, that does this? Can it somehow be extracted from `scatteredInterpolant` in reasonable processing time?

Comment: you want something like `griddata`?

Comment: `scatteredInterpolant` is a built-in function for which the code is not available so no chance to extract bits of it. Anyway, reading the documentation I don't think that it works the way you described with your weight matrix `W` which can be simply applied to any set of query point. The function **needs** the samples values as input. Along with the input coordinate, they will be used to create a surface `v=f(x,y)`. If your `(x,y)` pairs do not change but your scalar `v` change then the interpolating surface will change too. It cannot be reused for another complete different set of samples.

Comment: your best bet is to use the lowest level function matlab provide. First check if your sampling coordinates are on a regular grid, in which case use [`griddedinterpolant`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html) (_much faster_), if not a regular grid then [`scatteredinterpolant`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html) is your best option.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Unfortunately, `griddata` does not store the interpolation weights for reuse with other inputdata, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Hoki The weight matrix, `W`, is what my hypothetical interpolation method would use, not what is inside `scatteredInterpolant`. The question is how to build it. I believe it _can_ be extracted from a sequence of `scatteredInterpolant` objects by building them with delta functions, but that would be prohibitively expensive. So the question is, is there some other functionality in Matlab or something open source that does this. (The input grid is definitely irregular, btw).

Comment: The weights are value-dependent, so with a new set of values, you just need to call the function again

Comment: You can change the `Values` property of the interpolant. According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html#bvkm1tv-5) : "You get immediate results when you evaluate the new interpolant because the original triangulation does not change".

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm looking for a set of weights that is independent of the values. That is the main thrust of my question.

Comment: @rahnema Yes, but I still need to supply the query positions, which will trigger a recalculation of the interpolation weights. I was hoping to avoid that, I want the input _and_ output grid to be fixed.

Comment: Right, you want the linear system of equations that generates the outpu tof `scatteredinterpolant`. However, big assumption here, maybe that output is not generated by  a linear system of equations, and therefore not valid. Maybe you need to make your own linear system. B-splines may work for this?

Comment: Yes, I'm not tied to `scatteredInterpolant`, though, just using that as an example of something similar but slightly different. Yeah, I may have to make my own, though that is exactly what I wanted to avoid.